# Associating data with an identity

Tags: serialization

Assume that we have a thousand cows are in line to be milked.   If we wanted the queue wait time of a particular cow, measuring the arrival-times at the entrance and exit of the queue would not be enough: cows do not necessarily follow a FIFO compact.  Each arrival time measurement must be paired with a RFID measurement that is unique to the heffer.

By selecting a specific RFID datum (i.e a specific cow), the two arrival-times can be used to calculate the wait time.

## QUESTION

What is the name of the practice of the combining data, or in this case appending an the RFID to a measurement datapoint as in said example?

Comment: You have given a problem, but what is your question?

Comment: Thanks for the question.  Hopefully it is clear now.  If not, suggestions or questions are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand your problem. Maybe a solution to your example is:

You have a custom class

```
class Cow {
  var rfidTag: String?
  var queueEnteredAt: Date?
  var queueExitedAt: Date?
}
```

where `rfidTag` is initialized as soon as it is known.

For all cows, you can use an array or a set of `Cow` instances:

```
  var cows: [Cow]
```

that had to be initialized properly.

Now, when a cow enters or exits the queue, the RFID tag is scanned and one has to get access to the respective `cow` instance:

```
  let scannedCow = cows.filter { $0.rfidTag == scannedRFIDtag }.first
```

and a function is called that sets the respective property `queueEnteredAt` or `queueExitedAt` of this `cow`, say:

```
  scannedCow?.queueEnteredAt = Date()
```

Eventually, you can do any kind of statistics with the array.
PS: I am not sure if this helps, since the tag to your question is serialization and in the edit to your question you asked about naming...

**EDIT:**

If the RFID scanner delivers `scannedRFIDtag` on a separate thread, then you might indeed have a serialization problem, because 2 threads could try to access the cows array and set properties there concurrently. In this case you need to serialise the access, which could be done by redirecting the operations to the main queue (if only very little work is to be done):

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // serialised operations
  }
```

or by setting up a serial access queue:

```
private let serialAccessQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.xxx.yyy“)
```

and doing the work there:

```
  serialAlertQueue.sync {
    // serialised operations
  }
```